# wordpress img link

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, image

I'm working on a little blog made with wordpress.
I'm new in the CMS world.

I have one problem when i click on every images in the index.
Differently when I click on the title links, if I click on an image it opens a page where there aren't tags, category and text.

Any suggestion to solve the problem?

Thank you in advance.

wordpress blog link: http://www.studiover.net/annacosmesi

Comment: Reword your question, what is exactly the problem?

Comment: If my answer worked for you, could you please accept the answer? If it did not, can you please explain what was wrong with it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[You mean like this?](http://codegrad.hub.ph/removing-the-link-of-image-in-wordpress-attachment-page/)

Note that this fix will go away when Wordpress is updated. You may want to bookmark/favorite that URL.